# How to cross-reference a footnote in bookdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Bookdown have many cross-reference features. However, I was unable to find a solution to my problem.

Assume you have a `footnote[^1]` in the body of the document. Then you define the footnote as:

```
[^1]: Here is my footnote.
```

Now assume that you want to cross-reference that footnote. For example, see footnote `\@ref(label)`. I tried some different options with no success (like using `{#label}` after the footnote definition in `[^1]` or using `\@ref(^1)` as if `^1` was the label).

Maybe there is a simple solution to this and I am missing it. Or maybe it is necessary to have a specific structure as for figures `\@ref(eq:label)` and tables `\@ref(tab:label)`. Something like `\@ref(foot:label)` where we can insert a `{#label}` or `(#foot:label)` at the definition of footnote. Like

```
[^1]: Here is my footnote.{#lab}
```

or

```
[^1]: Here is my footnote.(#foot:lab)
```

Comment: This feature is not supported in bookdown. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Yihui. I'll open a pull request on github, because I think this would be a great feature. I need to cross-reference footnote quite often...